# elasticsearch warm indices read only

Tags: elasticsearch

Are warm indices on the warm data nodes, read-only indices or we can write to the indices on that node. The link here https://www.elastic.co/blog/hot-warm-architecture-in-elasticsearch-5-x states that the warm indices are read-only indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warm indices MUST NOT necessarily be read-only, it's only an advice to make them read-only in order to improve performance and get real benefits from a hot/warm architecture.

So the main idea of hot/warm setups is to keep recent data on hot hardware (fast but also more costly!) and move older data to warm hardware (slower and less costly). As you move older data to warm hardware, the assumption is that this data would not change anymore, hence why the recommendation of making those indices read-only. But it's not at all mandatory to do it.

Comment: you mean to say there is still a possibility of data being written to warm indices.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! You can set them to read-only, but it's not mandatory. The reason it's not recommended is because when indices transition from hot to warm they can be  force merged into fewer segments to optimize storage space and search performance. If you keep writing in them, that force merge step should not be done.